Conditional marker for scatterplot Matplotlib
I am trying to plot x1 and x2 against each other, and if class == 1, then marker should be +, if class == 0, then the marker should just be a dot.
The file.csv is structured like this, the class column which is the conditional will only be either 1 or 0:



x1
x2
mark




1
2
0


9
4
1


0
5
1


2
6
0



Here's the code I have:
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print(df)
x1 = df['x1'].to_numpy()
x2 = df['x2'].to_numpy()
mark = df['class'].to_numpy()
        
figure, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(0,80,1):
    if mark[i] > 0:
        ax.plot(x1[i], color="red", marker='o')
    else:
        ax.plot(x1[i], color="blue", marker='x')

This is what the result SHOULD look like: 

mark was originally "class" in my example, but I changed the variable name to mark since class is a Python keyword.

I would plot it this way for all the data, if you're going to select a subset, consider using a new dataframe to select the subset:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the rows where class is 1 and plot them with '+' marker
plt.scatter(df[df['class']==1]['x1'], df[df['class']==1]['x2'], marker='+')

# the rows where class is 0 and plot them with 'o' marker 
plt.scatter(df[df['class']==0]['x1'], df[df['class']==0]['x2'], marker='o')

plt.xlabel('x1') 
plt.ylabel('x2') 
plt.title('Scatter plot x1 vs x2') 
plt.show()



I'd correct one of your statements, as class is a Python keyword and you'd better leave those keywords alone.
What you want to do is easily done using np.where or, even more easily, using a helper function, as my x1x2select below.
If you subtract the imports and faking the data, you're left with three lines of code.
A final note, if you have an array arr=[0, 1] then 1-arr ⇒ [1, 0], that is the negation of the original array.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# you read a dataframe from a CSV file, I can't: me faking data
np.random.seed(20240903)
r = np.random.randint
N = range(80)
# my x1, x2, cl have the same data types as yours,
x1, x2, cl = [np.array(v) 
              for v in zip(*[[r(30,101),r(30,101),r(2)] for _ in N])]
# hence you can use my code with your initialized data

x1x2select = lambda v: np.where(v, (x1, x2), None)   ## 1
plt.plot(*x1x2select(  cl), 'ro', label='Positive')  ## 2
plt.plot(*x1x2select(1-cl), 'bx', label='Negative')  ## 3

plt.legend()
plt.show()


If you are interested in an interactive plot, and want to try out other packages on python. I would recommend using plotly.
This package allows for conditional symbols.
Here's some example code:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Example data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# Condition: Set different marker colors and symbols based on y values
color = np.where(y > 0, 'green', 'red')  # Green for y > 0, Red for y <= 0
symbol = np.where(y > 0, 'circle', 'cross')  # Circle for y > 0, Cross for y <= 0

# Create the scatter plot using Plotly
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x, y=y,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=color,  # Apply conditional colors
        symbol=symbol,  # Apply conditional symbols
        size=10,  # Marker size
        line=dict(width=2)
    ),
    name='Conditional Scatter'
))

# Add labels and title
fig.update_layout(
    title='Conditional Marker Scatter Plot',
    xaxis_title='x',
    yaxis_title='y',
)

# Show the figure
fig.show()

and Output
